# Processing Strings from data file containing punctuation coding in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple programme that can help make army lists for a popular tabletop wargame. More as an excercise for my own experience as there are plenty of pre made software packages that do this, but the idea behind it seems fairly straightforward

The programme reads the data for all the units available in an army from a spreadsheet and creates various classes for each unit. The main bit I am looking at now is the options/ upgrades.

In the file I want a straightforward syntax for the option field for each unit. i.e. the following options string `itemA, itemB/itemC-3, 2*itemD, itemE/itemF/itemG, itemH/itemI+itemJ` would mean

```
    1. you may take itemA (X pts per model)
    2. for every 3 models, you may exchange itemB with 
         a) itemC (net X pts per model)
    3. each model may take 2 of itemD (X pts per model)
    4. each model may take one of either 
         a)itemE (X pts per model)
         b)itemF (X pts per model)
         c)itemG (X pts per model
    5. each model may take either 
         a)itemH (X points per model)
         b)itemI and itemJ (X points per model)
```

At the moment I am processing the string using lots of splits and if statements, that make it very hard to keep track of and assign correctly once the user input their choice.

```
    for index, option in enumerate(self.options):
        output = "{}.".format(index+1)
        if '-' in option:
            sub_option, no_models = option.split('-')
            no_models = int(no_models)
            print(sub_option)
            print(no_models)
            output += "For every {} models ".format(no_models)
            if '/' in sub_option:
                temp_str, temp_options, points_list = exchange_option(sub_option)

            else:
                temp_str, temp_options, points_list = standard_option(sub_option)

            index_points.append(points_list)
            temp_options.append(no_models)
            index_options.append(temp_options)

        else:
            if '/' in option:
                temp_str, temp_options, points_list = exchange_option(option)
            else:
                temp_str, temp_options, points_list = standard_option(option)

            index_points.append(points_list)
            index_options.append(temp_options)

        output += temp_str
```

the `*_option()` functions are additional helper functions I have defined above which have a similar structure with further if statements within them.

The main question I am asking, is there an easier way to process a code like string such as this? While it works to produce the output in the example above it seems awfully cumbersome to then deal with the user input.

What I am aiming to do is first output the string as given in my example at the top of the question, and then taking the user input index of the given option, modify the associated unit class to have the correct wargear and points value.

I thought about trying to make some kind of options class, but again labelling and defining each option so that they can interact with one another properly seems equally complex, and I feel there must be something more pythonic or just generally better coding practice to processing encoded strings such as this?

Comment: To clarify: when given a string in the format you specified, the code should output a numbered list like the one in your question, right?

Comment: Yes, I have clarified my question with the precise output and what I want to do. Essentially I have the code working such that it outputs like it does in the example, but I'm wandering if there is a more straightforward way to store the options such that when a user input is given, the appropriate changes to the unit class being modified can be done i.e. adding items, exchanging items, or ensuring that there are enough models in the unit for the option to be valid. Rather than having to hard code lots of if statements to check the punctuation given in the string all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a full blown parser to do that! Now, this only outputs the list as in the previous version of your question, but it shouldn't be too hard to add more features as you want. Also please note that at the moment, the lexer does not error out when a string contains invalid tokens, but that's just a proof-of-concept, so it should be fine.

---

### Part I: the lexer

This tokenises the input string - looks through it from left to right and attempts to classify non-overlapping substrings as instances of tokens. It's to be used before parsing. When given a string, `Lexer.tokenize` yields a stream of `Token`s.

```
# FILE: lex.py

import re
import enum

class Token:
    def __init__(self, type, value: str, lineno: int, pos: int):
        self.type, self.value, self.lineno, self.pos = type, value, lineno, pos

    def __str__(self):
        v = f'({self.value!r})' if self.value else ''

        return f'{self.type.name}{v} at {self.lineno}:{self.pos}'

    __repr__ = __str__


class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, token_types: enum.Enum, tokens_regexes: dict):
        self.token_types = token_types

        regex = '|'.join(map('(?P<{}>{})'.format, *zip(*((tok.name, regex) for tok, regex in tokens_regexes.items()))))
        self.regex = re.compile(regex)


    def tokenize(self, string, skip=['space']):
        # TODO: detect invalid input

        lineno, pos = 0, 0
        skip = set(map(self.token_types.__getitem__, skip))

        for matchobj in self.regex.finditer(string):
            type_name = matchobj.lastgroup
            value = matchobj.groupdict()[type_name]

            Type = self.token_types[type_name]

            if Type == self.token_types.newline: # possibly buggy, but not catastrophic
                self.lineno += 1
                self.pos = 0
                continue

            pos = matchobj.end()

            if Type not in skip:
                yield Token(Type, value, lineno, pos)   

        yield Token(self.token_types.EOF, '', lineno, pos)
```

### Part II: the parser (with syntax-driven evaluation):

This parses the given stream of tokens provided by `lex.Lexer.tokenize` and translates individual symbols to English according to the following grammar:

```
Opt_list -> Option Opt_list_
Opt_list_ -> comma Option Opt_list_ | empty
Option -> Choice | Mult
Choice -> Compound More_choices Exchange
Compound -> item Add_item
Add_item -> plus item Add_item | empty
More_choices -> slash Compound More_choices | empty
Exchange -> minus num | empty
Mult -> num star Compound
```

The uppercase symbols are nonterminals, the lowercase ones are terminals. There's also a special symbol `EOF` that's not present here.

Also, take a look at the [vital statistics](http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/vital-stats.php?grammar=Opt_list%20-%3E%20Option%20Opt_list_.%0D%0AOpt_list_%20-%3E%20comma%20Option%20Opt_list_%20%7C.%0D%0AOption%20-%3E%20Choice%20%7C%20Mult.%0D%0AChoice%20-%3E%20Compound%20More_choices%20Exchange.%0D%0ACompound%20-%3E%20item%20Add_item.%0D%0AAdd_item%20-%3E%20plus%20item%20Add_item%20%7C.%0D%0AMore_choices%20-%3E%20slash%20Compound%20More_choices%20%7C.%0D%0AExchange%20-%3E%20minus%20num%20%7C.%0D%0AMult%20-%3E%20num%20star%20Compound.) of this grammar. This grammar is LL(1), so we can use an LL(1) recursive descent predictive parser, as shown below.

If you modify the grammar, you should modify the parser accordingly! The methods that do the actual parsing are called `parse_<something>`, and to change the output of the parser (the `Parser.parse` function, actually) you should change the return values of these `parse_<something>` functions.

```
# FILE: parse.py

import lex

class Parser:

    def __init__(self, lexer):
        self.string, self.tokens = None, None
        self.lexer = lexer
        self.t = self.lexer.token_types

        self.__lookahead = None

    @property
    def lookahead(self):
        if not self.__lookahead:
            try:
                self.__lookahead = next(self.tokens)
            except StopIteration:
                self.__lookahead = lex.Token(self.t.EOF, '', 0, -1)

        return self.__lookahead

    def next(self):
        if self.__lookahead and self.__lookahead.type == self.t.EOF:
            return self.__lookahead

        self.__lookahead = None
        return self.lookahead

    def match(self, token_type):
        if self.lookahead.type == token_type:
            return self.next()

        raise SyntaxError(f'Expected {token_type}, got {self.lookahead.type}', ('<string>', self.lookahead.lineno, self.lookahead.pos, self.string))

    # THE PARSING STARTS HERE
    def parse(self, string):
        # setup
        self.string = string
        self.tokens = self.lexer.tokenize(string)
        self.__lookahead = None
        self.next()

        # do parsing
        ret = [''] + self.parse_opt_list()

        return ' '.join(ret)

    def parse_opt_list(self) -> list:
        ret = self.parse_option(1)
        ret.extend(self.parse_opt_list_(1))

        return ret

    def parse_opt_list_(self, curr_opt_number) -> list:
        if self.lookahead.type in {self.t.EOF}:
            return []

        self.match(self.t.comma)

        ret = self.parse_option(curr_opt_number + 1)
        ret.extend(self.parse_opt_list_(curr_opt_number + 1))

        return ret

    def parse_option(self, opt_number) -> list:
        ret = [f'{opt_number}.']

        if self.lookahead.type == self.t.item:
            ret.extend(self.parse_choice())
        elif self.lookahead.type == self.t.num:
            ret.extend(self.parse_mult())
        else:
            raise SyntaxError(f'Expected {token_type}, got {self.lookahead.type}', ('<string>', self.lookahead.lineno, self.lookahead.pos, self.string))

        ret[-1] += '\n'

        return ret

    def parse_choice(self) -> list:
        c = self.parse_compound()
        m = self.parse_more_choices()
        e = self.parse_exchange()

        if not m:
            if not e:
                ret = f'You may take {" ".join(c)}'
            else:
                ret = f'for every {e} models you may take item {" ".join(c)}'
        elif m:
            c.extend(m)

            if not e:
                ret = f'each model may take one of: {", ".join(c)}'
            else:
                ret = f'for every {e} models you may exchange the following items with each other: {", ".join(c)}'
        else:
            ret = 'Semantic error!'

        return [ret]


    def parse_compound(self) -> list:
        ret = [self.lookahead.value]

        self.match(self.t.item)
        _ret = self.parse_add_item()

        return [' '.join(ret + _ret)]

    def parse_add_item(self) -> list:
        if self.lookahead.type in {self.t.comma, self.t.minus, self.t.slash, self.t.EOF}:
            return []

        ret = ['with']   
        self.match(self.t.plus)

        ret.append(self.lookahead.value)
        self.match(self.t.item)

        return ret + self.parse_add_item()


    def parse_more_choices(self) -> list:
        if self.lookahead.type in {self.t.comma, self.t.minus, self.t.EOF}:
            return []

        self.match(self.t.slash)
        ret = self.parse_compound()

        return ret + self.parse_more_choices()


    def parse_exchange(self) -> str:
        if self.lookahead.type in {self.t.comma, self.t.EOF}:
            return ''

        self.match(self.t.minus)

        ret = self.lookahead.value
        self.match(self.t.num)

        return ret

    def parse_mult(self) -> list:
        ret = [f'each model may take {self.lookahead.value} of:']

        self.match(self.t.num)
        self.match(self.t.star)

        return ret + self.parse_compound()
```

### Part III: usage

Here's how to use all of that code:

```
# FILE: evaluate.py

import enum

from lex import Lexer
from parse import Parser


# these are all the types of tokens present in our grammar
token_types = enum.Enum('Types', 'item num plus minus star slash comma space newline empty EOF')

t = token_types

# these are the regexes that the lexer uses to recognise the tokens
terminals_regexes = {
    t.item: r'[a-zA-Z_]\w*',
    t.num: '0|[1-9][0-9]*',
    t.plus: r'\+',
    t.minus: '-',
    t.star: r'\*',
    t.slash: '/',
    t.comma: ',',
    t.space: r'[ \t]',
    t.newline: r'\n'
}

lexer = Lexer(token_types, terminals_regexes)
parser = Parser(lexer)

string = 'itemA, itemB/itemC-3, 2*itemD, itemE/itemF/itemG, itemH/itemI+itemJ'
print(f'STRING FROM THE QUESTION: {string!r}\nRESULT:')
print(parser.parse(string), '\n\n')


string = input('Enter a command: ')

while string and string.lower() not in {'q', 'quit', 'e', 'exit'}:
    try:
        print(parser.parse(string))
    except SyntaxError as e:
        print(f'    Syntax error: {e}\n    {e.text}\n' + ' ' * (4 + e.offset - 1) + '^\n')

    string = input('Enter a command: ')
```

### Example session:

```
# python3 evaluate.py

STRING FROM THE QUESTION: 'itemA, itemB/itemC-3, 2*itemD, itemE/itemF/itemG, itemH/itemI+itemJ'
RESULT:
 1. You may take itemA
 2. for every 3 models you may exchange the following items with each other: itemB, itemC
 3. each model may take 2 of: itemD
 4. each model may take one of: itemE, itemF, itemG
 5. each model may take one of: itemH, itemI with itemJ



Enter a command: itemA/b/c/stuff
 1. each model may take one of: itemA, b, c, stuff

Enter a command: 4 * anything
 1. each model may take 4 of: anything

Enter a command: 5 * anything + more
 1. each model may take 5 of: anything with more

Enter a command: a + b + c+ d
 1. You may take a with b with c with d

Enter a command: a+b/c
 1. each model may take one of: a with b, c

Enter a command: itemA/itemB-2
 1. for every 2 models you may exchange the following items with each other: itemA, itemB

Enter a command: itemA+itemB/itemC - 5
 1. for every 5 models you may exchange the following items with each other: itemA with itemB, itemC

Enter a command: q
```

Comment: This is great thank you so much! I was just wandering if you could explain what statements like `value:int` mean in the declaration and what `->` does. The code works beautifully though. Can you recommend any further tutorials on parsers as this is definitely something I can look into more with the rest of the programme as I am hoping to output documents at the end!

Comment: `value:int` and code like `def function() -> type:` are [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). These typically don't affect the operation of code. I'm studying (well, just "looking into", I guess) parsers myself at the moment, and I find [CS143: Compilers](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/) by the Stanford University very helpful. It's not exclusively about parsers, but it includes 8 lectures and 10 handouts about this topic.